# Is it possible to get children in custom component?

Tags: nativescript

Is it possible to get children in custom component?

```
<myCustomComponent>
    <Label #id1 text="ID 1"></Label>
    <Label #id2 text="ID 2"></Label>
</myCustomComponent>
```

Is there a way to get the reference of these two `Lable` to get them positioned in a `GridLayout` in my custom component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the option with getViewById() there are several options to see the a layout's children or their index and also to add, remove, insert and reset children.

e.g.
***page.xml***

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
    <StackLayout id="st" class="p-20">
        <Label id="lbl-title" text="Tap the button" class="h1 text-center"/>
        <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"/>
        <Label text="{{ message }}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

***page.ts***

```
let page = <Page>args.object;
let stack = <StackLayout>page.getViewById("st");
let label = <Label>page.getViewById("lbl-title");

console.log("page.content: " + page.content); // page.content: StackLayout<st>@file:///app/main-page.xml:19:5;

console.log("stack.getChildrenCount(): " + stack.getChildrenCount()) // 3
console.log("stack.getChildAt(1): " + stack.getChildAt(1)); // stack.getChildAt(1): Button(5)@file:///app/main-page.xml:21:9;
console.log("stack.getChildIndex(label): " + stack.getChildIndex(label)); // 0

console.log("stack.parent: " + stack.parent); // stack.parent: Page(1)@file:///app/main-page.xml:7:1;

var newlabel = new Label();
newlabel.text = "new Label";
stack.addChild(newlabel);
```

More about all supported methods [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_layouts_layout_.layout.html)

Answer (score 2):

The view class has a [getViewById()](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view.html#getviewbyid) method for this purpose.

In my-component.xml:

```
<StackLayout loaded="onLoaded">
    <Label id="label1" text="ID 1" mycustomattribute="Hi there."></Label>
    <Label id="label2" text="ID 2"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

In my-component.js:

```
exports.onLoaded = function(args) {

    let view = args.object;
    let label1 = view.getViewById('label1');
    console.log(label1.mycustomattribute);
    // > "Hi there."
};
```